# Setting PostgreSQL privileges for ArcGIS?

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.4, pgadmin-4

I'm migrating from SQL Server and setting up my first PostgreSQL server for use with ArcGIS.  I've followed esri tutorials and related how-tos.  I'll be using a versioned editing environment, as I will want numerous users editing simultaneously.  I'm attempting to set up users/roles following the [Esri documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/databases/privileges-db-postgresql.htm):

I've created an "editor" role for editing, using pgAdmin.  I've also created an "owner" user for creating versions, using the [Create Database User geoprocessing tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-database-user.htm).  The owner has an "owner" schema in the database, and I've granted USAGE on the schema to the editor role.  Sufficient privileges are granted to the "editor" role to allow user in the role to edit data.

At this point, the owner can create datasets, feature classes, etc, while the editor can only **edit** current objects within the dataset.  I've noticed the editor can also create new feature datasets within the geodatabase, but is unable to create new objects in the new feature dataset.

Is there a privilege I can revoke from the editor to disable it from being able to create feature datasets?

Comment: Nope.  FDS don't exist as ojects in the database, just as properties in the geodatabase metadata.

Comment: @Vince thank you, that makes sense.  Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Maybe? I'd have to scour the docs through Google to see, but my time is constrained by delivery deadlines and POP closure.